# Why isn't anything being inserted into my MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I have some PDO that I'm trying to use to insert data into a MySQL table.

```
private function addResource() {
    include('./dbconnect.php');
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_password);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO Resources VALUES (?, $title, $url, $_SESSION[\'tblUserID\'');
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $url);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $_SESSION['tblUserID']);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() != 1)
        throw new Exception('Could not add resource');
    $status = true;
}
```

Thing is, whenever I check the table, nothing is being inserted. How come?

EDIT: I have session_start() at the top of the page.

Comment: You're adding three parameters to the query, but there's only one placeholder. Try replacing $title, $url, and $_SESSION[\'tblUserID\' with additional question marks. What does the existing placeholder add?

Comment: If you're using prepared statements, why are you also interpolating variables into the string?

Comment: You should put `try`/`catch` handlers around the PDO method calls so you see the errors in your SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're using PDO completely wrong. Placeholders do not use PHP variable syntax. The query string should be:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO .... VALUES (:id, :title, :url, :userid')
                                                     ^^^^^^
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
                  ^^^^^^
```

Note the use of the `:whatever` format for placeholders.

As it is written now, your query is a flat-out syntax error, and vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about that.

Comment: Looks like you forgot a trailing quote and it's causing the syntax highlighter to freak out.

Comment: I think it's still buggy, but I did wrap it in a try/catch and took the variables out of the prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private function addResource() {
      include('./dbconnect.php');
      try{
          $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_password);
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO Resources VALUES (:title, :url, :userid)';
          $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
          $stmt->bindParam(':url', $url);
          $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $_SESSION['tblUserID']);
          $stmt->execute();
          if ($stmt->rowCount() != 1)
            throw new Exception('Could not add resource');
          $status = true;
          }
       }catch (Exception $e){
          echo $e->getMessage();
          exit;
       }
    }
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I tried adding the try/catch as indicated here, but I am not getting any exceptions.

Comment: Did it insert the data into your table? It won't show any exceptions unless there is an error. Try adding `echo $title;` to your code and see if it outputs a what you expect. If it does not maybe remove `private function . . .` and make it just `function addResource() . . .`